# Is "parsing" a subset of "compiling"?

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, terminology

When I think of "compiling" I think of turning C++ code into a binary. Or perhaps C# into CLR byte code. But "parsing" could be something like parsing Python, or a web template language, where it doesn't need to produce any binaries, but can either execute the code immediately, statement-by-statement, or output HTML directly.

Would you basically be doing the same task in either case? Ignoring the language syntax, would compiling C++ be equally as difficult as parsing a website template file (Django, Smarty, whatever), or Python?

What I'm trying to allude at, is **if I study "compiling" or read a book on "compiling" will I necessarily pick up the skills to parse non-compiled languages?**

Comment: compiling requires parsing, but parsing does not require compiling.  There is a relationship, but not an is-a relationship.

Comment: Adding another piece to the puzzle, in asp.net we can deploy the source code files directly without compilation due to [Dynamic Compilation!](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366723.aspx)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**Short answer**: parsing is *not* a subset of compiling.

**Long answer**: generally, there are a 3 steps to converting source to another format:

1. Lexing, which converts some form of input to a token stream.
2. Parsing, which converts the token stream into an abstract syntax tree (AST).
3. Compiling, which converts the AST into a set of executable instructions (native code, byte code, etc).

(For very simple languages, you may not even need a parser, you might be able to compile the token stream directly, or your parser could output native code directly.)

So start with a raw string like this:

```
let x = 0
while x < 10
    print x
    x := x + 1
```

A lexer is going to convert it into a token stream, probably something like this:

```
[LET; String("x"); EQ; Int(0); NEWLINE; WHILE; String("x");
 LT; VAL(10); ... ]
```

The parser will convert the stream into a more meaningful data structure, your abstract syntax tree:

```
// AST definition
type expr =
    | Block of expr list
    | Assign of string * expr
    | While of expr * expr
    | Call of string * expr list
    | Add of expr * expr
    | Var of string
    | Int of int

// AST instance created from token stream
Block
    [
        Assign("x", Int(10));
        While
        (
            LessThan(Var("x"), Int(10)),
            Block
                [
                    Call("print", [Var("x")]);
                    Assign("x", Add(Var("x"), Int(1)));
                ]
        );
    ]
```

Once you have an AST, you can do whatever it wants with it:

- You convert the AST to native code (compiling).
- or you could interpret the AST on the fly, which you might do with a dynamic programming language or a templating engine.
- or you could iterate the AST to make a syntax highlighter.
- or you could walk the AST and output equivalent code in another language.
- or you could look for all instances of `Var("x")` and replace them with `Var("y")` similar to a code refactor tool).

So, while you usually parse input before compiling, that's not the same as saying that parsing is a subset of compiling.

Comment: Wow. Wasn't expecting such a detailed answer. Thank you! Didn't know this :)

Answer (score 5):

No, parsing and compiling can be completely independent.

- A parser may not be emitting any code at all. It could be parsing some data object (JSON, XML, whatever)
- A compiler may not have source code to start with - it could be presented with an abstract syntax tree, already parsed, and just have to emit the relevant code

Most compilers *include* a parsing step, but I don't think it's necessarily a "subset" of compiling, and parsing certainly doesn't have to have anything to do with compilation.

Comment: If you are compiling source code, then I believe parsing is necessary.

Comment: @jjnguy: I'd agree. However, I'd argue that a compiler doesn't always have source code as its input. A JIT compiler is one example.

Answer (score 2):

..."will I pick up skills to parse non-compiled languages?"  Yes, you will, but you can study parsing by itself.

What you will find, however, is that much of compiling (name resolution, type inference, pattern matching, compiling to instructions [pcode rather than machine code], high-performance execution, optimizing for special cases) is useful in *processing* non-compiled languages.  So if you intend to do more than just literally *parse*, you'll want to study compiler technology anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Compiling is actually more difficult than parsing since its just one of the preliminary steps in compiling.

After the parsing, a symbol table is generated from which the actual binary code is generated.

In interpreting languages such as Javascript, the statements can be executed as each statement is parsed.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing